# Unzip a LARGE zip file in Azure File Storage w/o "Out of Memory" exception"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, zip

Here's what I'm dealing with...

Some process (out of our control) will occasionally drop a zip file into a directory in Azure File Storage.  That directory name is `InBound`. So let's say a file called `bigbook.zip` is dropped into the `InBound` folder.

I need to create an Azure Function App that runs every 5 minutes and looks for zip files in the `InBound` directory. If any exists, then one-by-one, we create a new directory by the same name as the zip file in another directory (called `InProcess`). So in our example, I would create `InProcess/bigbook`.

Now inside `InProcess/bigbook`, I need to unzip `bigbook.zip`. So by the time the process is done running `InProcess/bigbook` will contain all the contents of `bigbook.zip`.

Please note: This function I am creating is a Console App that will run as an Azure Function App. So there will be no file system access (at least, as far as I'm aware, anyway.)  There is no option to *download* the zip file, unzip it, and then move the contents.

I am having a devil of a time figuring out how to do this in memory only. No matter what I try, I keep running into an Out Of Memory exception. For now, I am just doing this on my localhost running in debug in Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.7.  In that setting, I am not able to convert the test zip file, which is 515,069KB.

This was my first attempt:

```
    private async Task<MemoryStream> GetMemoryStreamAsync(CloudFile inBoundfile)
    {
        MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
        await inBoundfile.DownloadToStreamAsync(memstream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return memstream;
    }
```

And this (with high hopes) was my second attempt, thinking that `DownloadRangeToStream` would work better than just `DownloadToStream`.

```
    private MemoryStream GetMemoryStreamByRange(CloudFile inBoundfile)
    {
        MemoryStream outPutStream = new MemoryStream();
        inBoundfile.FetchAttributes();
        int bufferLength = 1 * 1024 * 1024;//1 MB chunk
        long blobRemainingLength = inBoundfile.Properties.Length;
        long offset = 0;
        while (blobRemainingLength > 0)
        {
            long chunkLength = (long)Math.Min(bufferLength, blobRemainingLength);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                inBoundfile.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, offset, chunkLength);
                lock (outPutStream)
                {
                    outPutStream.Position = offset;
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    outPutStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }

            offset += chunkLength;
            blobRemainingLength -= chunkLength;
        }
        return outPutStream;
    }
```

But either way, I am running into memory issues. I presume it's because the MemoryStream I am trying to create gets too large?

How else can I tackle this?  And again, downloading the zip file is not an option, as the app will ultimately be an Azure Function App. I'm also pretty sure that using a FileStream isn't an option either, as that requires a local file path, which I don't have. (I only have a remote Azure URL)

Could I somehow create a temp file in the same Azure Storage account that the zip file is in, and stream the zip file to that temp file instead of to a memory stream? (Thinking out loud.)

The goal is to get the stream into a `ZipArchive` using:

```
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream)
```

And from there I can extract all the contents.  But getting to that point w/o memory errors is proving a real bugger.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using CloudFile? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile?view=azure-dotnet 
CloudFile has methods to create, copy and delete. Might do the trick for you.

Comment: @Sean, thank you, but I'm not sure what you mean I *AM* using a CloudFile. Both of the methods I put in the OP take a parameter `(CloudFile inBoundfile)`. What I need to do is convert that CloudFile to a stream so I can use it in `ZipArchive(stream)'.  That's the whole problem I'm having.

Comment: I meant the cloud file class. You mentioned you only have the Azure URL. CloudFile has a constructor that takes a URI. You might be able to create a new Cloudfile object from your url then open the cloud file stream.

Comment: I'm still not sure how that helps my get any closer to my ultimate goal. Maybe I'm not understanding?  I have a CloudFile, and what you are saying is that I should use the URL of that CloudFile to create another CloudFile?  What I need to do is take an *existing* CloudFile and convert it to a memory stream.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, it's working fine at my local computer by using DownloadToStream(memory_stream), and the .zip file is around 600M. And it will take up about 600M memory about my local computer during download. Can you just push your code to azure, to see if it's working?

Comment: @IvanYang, thanks, and your comment is both good news but also frustrating! After the zip file is converted to a stream, I have a ton of logic I need to perform. I'm going to have to get this working on my localhost if I have any hope of properly coding the rest of this function.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Sorry, guess I was more tired last night than I realized. I couldn't find anything in the azure sdk docs for ZipArchive, do you have a link for the documentation? I was able to create a simple Timer Function that copies files from one directory in Azure to another (I used 500 Mb and 1Gb files for testing).

Comment: "I couldn't find anything in the azure sdk docs for ZipArchive"
Yeah me neither. Don't think it exists. But if I can just convert the CloudFile to a MemoryStream then all my troubles will go away.  From the MemoryStream, I can create a ZipArchive (independent of anything to do with Azure.)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, can you open the task manager to observe the memory changes in your localhost during download? Maybe it's caused by the available memory in your localhost is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Azure Storage File Share this is the only way it worked for me without loading the entire ZIP into Memory. I tested with a 3GB ZIP File (with thousands of files or with a big file inside) and Memory/CPU was low and stable. I hope it helps!

```
var zipFiles = _directory.ListFilesAndDirectories()
    .OfType<CloudFile>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(".zip"))
    .ToList();

foreach (var zipFile in zipFiles)
{
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipFile.OpenRead()))
    {
        foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Length > 0)
            {
                CloudFile extractedFile = _directory.GetFileReference(entry.Name);

                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                    using (var ms = extractedFile.OpenWrite(entry.Length))
                    {
                        int read;
                        while ((read = entryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use memory snapshots to see why you are running out of memory within Visual Studio. You can use the tutorial in [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/) to find the culprit. Doing local development with a smaller file may help you continue to work if your machine is simply running out of memory.

When it comes to doing this within Azure, a node in the Consumption plan is [limited to 1.5GB of total memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale). If you expect to receive files larger than that then you should look at one of the other App Service plans that give you more memory to work with.

It is possible to store files within the [function's local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973998/storing-state-locally-with-azure-functions), so that is an option. You can't guaruntee that you will be using the same local directory between executions, but this should work as long as you are using the file you downloaded within the same execution.